Springboot mySQL Failed to determine a suitable driver class
this is my property file:
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://lin-836046-17428-mysql-primary.servers.linodedb.net:3306/mailing_db
spring.datasource.username=mailing_usr
spring.datasource.password=7Erge8O9Pc5zIq,mN
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

but I have this error when starting:
2024-07-04 13:32:52.048 [main] DEBUG [] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter@report(37) - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.getDriverClassName(PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at com.absoludekontroll.MailApplication.main(MailApplication.java:14)
2024-07-04 13:32:52.049 [main] ERROR [] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter@report(40) - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

here my dependencies:
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver or similar needed in there. Though I'm not sure why, since the provider system should be being used

Well have you read the stacktrace? Did you include the mysql driver as a dependency (judging from the error you haven't).

Don't add MySQL driver as dependency twice, the driver should be registered to the proper classpath.

add spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver and also add the dependency mysql-connector-java, you added "mysql-connector-j" also try not only to add it in runtime

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

you only added "mysql-connector-j" and try remvoing the scope.
Then also in the properties add the following:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

